# Char(39) - Delphi XE7 + Firedac + Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, delphi

I've got a problem using Delphi Xe 7 + Firedac + Postgresql. I'm trying a "nextval" using a FDQuery, but when I set the Char 39 using `FDQuery.sql.add` method, the char 39 is changed for `''`.

example, if I try:

```
'select nextval('+Char(39)+'tb_borg_answer_id_seq'+Char(39)+') as id'
```

I get:

```
'select nextval(''tb_borg_answer_id_seq'') as id'
```

somebody knows why?

[Edit]

Thanks for all.
I'm trying to call nextval method from a FDQuery.

I do this: 
FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery.SQL.Add(' SELECT NEXTVAL(''seq_name'')');

After add, in debug, the command FDQuery.SQL[0] returns:
'SELECT NEXTVAL(''seq_name'')'. 
This cause an exception in postgresql, because postgresql is waiting for this:
SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name')

I tried this too, but don't works:
FDQuery.SQL.Add(' SELECT NEXTVAL('+Char(39)+'seq_name'+Char(39)+')');

Always FDQuery.SQL[0] write '' instead of '

Comment: I am guessing that it has something to do with this: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Preprocessing_Command_Text.html - the way to change this is to use http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=uADStanOption_TADResourceOptions_EscapeExpand.html or http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/uADStanOption_TADResourceOptions_PreprocessCmdText.html

Comment: Nothing in those links describe this particular behavior for character #39.

Comment: @Gui: `Char(39)` is the `'` character, which is Delphi's quotation mark for denoting string/character literals. `''` is how the `'` character is expressed inside of a literal. `FDQuery.SQL.Add('select nextval('+Char(39)+'tb_borg_answer_id_seq'+Char(39)+') as id')` and `FDQuery.SQL.Add('select nextval(''tb_borg_answer_id_seq'') as id')` are passing the *exact same string value* to `Add()`.  So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Tks Lebeau, my actual problem is the change of ' for ''

I do this: FDQuery.SQL.Clear; FDQuery.SQL.Add(' SELECT NEXTVAL(''seq_name'')');

and  FDQuery.SQL[0] returns
'SELECT NEXTVAL(''seq_name'')'

postgresql is waiting for SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name')
and
SELECT NEXTVAL(''seq_name'')
raise a postgres exception

Comment: As @RemyLebeau said, it's how it's expressed inside of a literal - the debugger shows it that way. Assign a local string variable to your string and view it in the debugger - it will show it the same way.  Have you run a DB monitor over the actual SQL statement being executed to know this is the problem?  What exception are you getting?

Comment: Man... I solved it.. you'll not believe... the problem was in a other module that was not saving my DB connection config.. 

I was logged in other base!!! and postgresql wasn't finding my seq name...

3 days to fix it... that's crazy!!

Thanks very much!